# Shiny - how to center and fix width of dashboard

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

Hello R Studio Community,

I've been developing an app in Shiny and it's be great. I have one simple question.

As different browsers have different widths, is there a way to set the rule on resizing the Shiny dashboard based on the following:

1) If browser width is more than x, limit to width to x and center the entire dashboard

2) If browser width is less than x, follow default autosizing

3) Not essential. But how do I set the blank space color to the left and right of the dashboard

[image: Fix width shiny dashboard]

The motivation is that I need a fixed width so that some pictures are scaled correctly. I hope my request can be done through some div tag on the dashboardPage.

This is the current behavior which I do NOT want.

[Shiny dashboard stretches to fit window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVtCH.jpg)

Cheers,
Donny

Comment: Not sure I understand- are you saying that your shinydashboard is not automatically resizing to the browser window?

Comment: I felt the inference of my question was obvious. Nonetheless, I've added a detail to make my request clearer.

Comment: OK. I guess  don't know the answer to your question. My opinion would be to use images that look fine when scaled to a typical browser window size. Seems like an easier fix to me but I don't know your use case. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi to achive what you are asking for just add the following code to the beginning of your `dashboardBody`. something like this

```
dashboardBody(

    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "body{
    min-height: 611px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
        }"
      )
    ),
   ... #the rest of you ui code
```

hope this helps

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you. I'm gonna add a "background-color: slategrey" at the end. Cheers.